# Syncing/Mirroring two partitions (Sata, USB) : RAID or not?

Tags: raid, dd, mirrors

My 12.04 Ubuntu server has a 120Go internal SATA `sda5`, ext4 partition. I also own a 500 Go USB2 external hard-drive from which I could easily free 120 Go.

Now, I've been meaning to set up mirroring (there is a lot of valuable data on this server for me) so that my system could handle a disk failure without losing more than, let's say, a couple of hours of work.

For this reason, my question are :

- Would RAID-1 be an overkill, given that 
  1°) The USB hard drive might throttle the write-read rates ? 
  2°) As I said, I would be just fine with a system cloning every hour or so, and I don't really mind a downtime in case of a single disk failure.
- I've seen that `dd` is able to clone partition, and I could set up a cron-job for cheap mirroring, but is there a rsync-like `dd` that would exploit the fact that most of the data has not changed ?

## Update

I'm of course talking here of a logical RAID.

Comment: what about a schedule backup of your data every 1 hour? and you can also create a logical volume that act like raid 1 .